# Glide transition doesn't works with listener?

Tags: android-glide

I have my Glide code below

```
    Glide.with(this)
            .load("https://flybubble.com/media/wysiwyg/images/home/mainpage-box-5L.jpg")
            .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
            .apply(RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .transforms(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(1000)))
            .into(my_image_view)
```

All works fine, where when the image is loaded, the `withCrossFade()` shows it fades in.

However, when I add listener to it as below

```
    Glide.with(this)
            .load("https://flybubble.com/media/wysiwyg/images/home/mainpage-box-5L.jpg")
            .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
            .apply(RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .transforms(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(1000)))
            .listener(object: RequestListener<Drawable>{
                override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any, target: Target<Drawable>, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    return false
                }
                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable, model: Any, target: Target<Drawable>, dataSource: DataSource, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    my_image_view.setImageDrawable(resource)
                    return true
                }
            })
            .into(my_image_view)
```

The `withCrossFade()` can no longer work. Is it because `transition` doesn't works with `listener`, or I miss something?

Answer (score 3):

Found the way to do it is not through transition, but a `Transition` that feeds the `target.onResourceReady` instead.

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load("https://flybubble.com/media/wysiwyg/images/home/mainpage-box-5L.jpg")
        //.transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade()) //Remove this line
        .apply(RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .centerCrop()
                .transforms(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(1000)))
        .listener(object: RequestListener<Drawable>{
            override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any, target: Target<Drawable>, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                return false
            }
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable, model: Any, target: Target<Drawable>, dataSource: DataSource, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                target.onResourceReady(resource, DrawableCrossFadeTransition(1000, !isFirstResource))
                return true
            }
        })
        .into(my_image_view)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without consulting with Glide docs, I'd say that this is because you have overridden Glides part of the job. You took the `Drawable` that the library has fetched for you in `onResourceReady` and, instead of loading the image with Glide, you've forced it in your `ImageView`. In this example, I'd compare Glides function as just a drawable downloader, while you are the one that loads the image into a view.

Comment: It would be helpful to show me the code that works with listener, while having the transition works. The above code works if you copy and paste into an Android project with Glide library, so you could experiment it.

Comment: In that case, I'd need to know what's the purpose of the listener. Currently, all it does is interfere with Glides image loading process.

Comment: The listener is not doing anything, other than just showing the image. I'm just experimenting how to use the listener.